# Lloyd's Algorithm and convergence conditions

Tags: compactness, fixed-point-theorems, numerical-optimization, compact-operators, voronoi-diagram

I need help understanding the following theorem about Lloyd's algorithm ([Du's Convergence of the Lloyd Algorithm for Computing Centroidal Voronoi Tessellations, Theorem 2.6](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/040617364)). Lloyd's algorithm is used to compute Centroidal Voronoi Tessellations.

Theorem: If the iterations in the Lloyd algorithm stay in a compact set,
where the Lloyd map $\mathbb{T}$ is continuous, then the algorithm is globally convergent to a
critical point of $\mathbb{H}$.

Here, $\mathbb{T}$ maps a set of generator points in a convex subset of $\mathbb{S}\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ to a new set of centroids also in $\mathbb{S}$. The function $\mathbb{H}$ is an energy function and it means that it decreases (until it reaches some minimum) over iterations.

My problem is understanding the premise. What does it mean by "*If the iterations in the Lloyd algorithm stay in a compact set*"? The new centroid by definition will remain within the convex set $\mathbb{S}$ so the generators are always inside a compact set. Does it means that every new point (generator) belongs to the same Voronoi cell as the iteration before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $n$ generators in $d$-dimensional space, the Lloyd map is a function ${\bf T}: X\rightarrow X$ where $X\subset {\mathbb R}^{nd}$. $X$ is strict subset of ${\mathbb R}^{nd}$ since two generators cannot coincide, i.e. $X = \left\{ \{{\bf Z_i}\}_{i=1}^n\,|\, {\bf Z}_j \neq {\bf Z}_k \,{\rm for\, any}\, j \neq k \right\}$. This set $X$ is not [compact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_space#Basic_examples) (in the normal sense in ${\mathbb R}^{nd}$) since points in $X$ can be arbitrarily close to points where generators do not coincide (which are not in $X$). The theorem is referring to a compact subset of this domain (of the Lloyd map) in ${\mathbb R}^{nd}$, not the underlying space of the generators ${\mathbb R}^{d}$.

The theorem is saying that if the Lloyd iteration can be restricted to a compact subset of $X$, then any limit points of the algorithm are well-defined centroidal Voronoi tessellations. But this is almost a tautology: phrased another way it says "if the iterations stay in a set that does not contain any degenerate accumulation points, then iteration cannot approach any degenerate points".

The theorem appears to say something stronger: if iteration stays in a compact set, then there is a single limit and that limit is a centroidal Voronoi tessellation. But that overstates the "global convergence theorem" which really says that *any* limit point of the iteration is a centroidal Voronoi tessellation without guaranteeing a single limit. For reference, there is a relatively concise explanation of the "Global Convergence Theorem" [here](http://www.math.udel.edu/~angell/gl_conv.pdf) with a clearer description of the conclusions that can be drawn.

Comment: Alex, you are awesome! thanks a lot!

Comment: Link is broken @Alex